# Is it possible traverse an ignite cache in index order?

Tags: caching, indexing, ignite

Looking at the indexing documentation here http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/sql-queries, I see that that indexes are nothing more than a sorted version of the original data.

What we need to do is traverse all the elements of the cached object's local entry's values, on each node.  So say on a node, we have the values

```
ID    Values
A     1,2
B     2,3,4
C     1,4
```

We want to traverse it in this order

```
1 A
1 C
2 A
2 B
3 B
4 B
4 C
```

My two quetions are, is it possible to create such indexes when we effectively have a multi-map cache?  And if it is possible, can we simple traverse the local entries in the order they are in the cache.  This would all us to traverse our data without any custom data-structure building code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You have to store each value individually to create such an index.

Comment: I figured as much, what about the second question.  Assuming we build a normal index that works.  Can you traverse it in order either via a select statement or accessing the underlying index?  (On each node locally to benefit for data locality)

Comment: The answer is most likely NO, but I'm not sure I understand the business use case. Can you give more details?

Comment: We need to partition data on one variable, but then traverse in a specific order not having to do with the key.  So if we index it on that key, we could *hopefully* just run through it via the index

Comment: Sounds like you can utilize affinity collocation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#collocate-data-with-data

Comment: We also need to traverse it in order though, which is the part I was hoping we could get an index for.  We have a work around though, instead of partitioning on that key we are creating an artificial key with the indexed set as the value.  However, this artificial key (by definition) is partitioned as necessary.  So now we can just iterate on local entries on each node.  Thanks for your dedication to the ignite questions!